# How to plot randomly?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, random

Is is possible to have a plot, something like [This random triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410054/generate-random-locations-within-a-triangular-domain), but instead of `.` we have Roses?
I mean, How can we plot the below Rose in random locations??

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t,k = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000),5


x = np.cos(k*t)*np.cos(t)
y = np.cos(k*t)*np.sin(t)


plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.axis('off')
plt.axis('square')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes! you just plot your rose at lots of random points as sampled from your linked out question.

first I've refactored the method so it returns `size` points uniformly sampled within the given triangle:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def trisample(A, B, C, size=1):
  r1 = np.random.rand(size)
  r2 = np.random.rand(size)

  s1 = np.sqrt(r1)
  p1 = 1 - s1
  p2 = (1 - r2) * s1
  p3 = r2 * s1

  x = A[0] * p1 + B[0] * p2 + C[0] * p3
  y = A[1] * p1 + B[1] * p2 + C[1] * p3

  return x, y
```

next we calculate a few of your roses:

```
t, k, z = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 5*5+1), 5, 0.1

x_r = np.cos(k*t) * np.sin(t) * z
y_r = np.cos(k*t) * np.cos(t) * z
```

note that your `pi*2` meant that it was orbited twice so I've dropped that, also I only use 5 points per "petal" to speed things up.  `z` scales the roses down so they fit into the triangle

finally we sample some points in the triangle, and plot them as you did:

```
for x_t, y_t in zip(*trisample([1,1], [5,3], [2,5], 100)):
  plt.plot(x_r + x_t, y_r + y_t, lw=1)

plt.axis('off')
plt.axis('square');
```

which gives something like the following:

[image: triangle filled with roses]

Answer (score 1):

You need a random start point for the rose. I guess you could something like thatin this manner:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

t,k = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000),5

x_start = random.randint(0, 10)
y_start = random.randint(0, 10)

x = x_start + np.cos(k*t)*np.cos(t)
y = y_start + np.cos(k*t)*np.sin(t)


plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.axis('off')
plt.axis('square')
plt.show()
```