# Sampling random points from an implicitly defined surface in Python

Tags: python, random, sympy, surface

I have an implicitly defined hypersurface in R^3, given by the zero level set of some function F:

> F(x,y,z) = 0.

This part may not matter but: I want to plot this surface using the answers given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680525/plotting-implicit-equations-in-3d) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484527/is-it-possible-to-plot-implicit-equations-using-matplotlib) thread.

Now I want to take a random sample of points from this surface. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the surface bounded? Can you compute the bounds? Is the surface parametrisable? Do you care about the uniformity of the sampling distribution? Maybe choose random values for 2 out of 3 variables and then solve for the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, simple way would be:

1. Triangulate implicit surface. For implicit surface there are variations of marching cubes, I believe, already done.
2. Given list of triangles, compute total area A=Sum(A<sub>i</sub>), and probabilities p<sub>i</sub> = A<sub>i</sub>/A. Probabilities would be normalized, Sum(p<sub>i</sub>)=1
3. Sample particular triangle *i* using probabilities p<sub>i</sub>. Numpy.random.choice should help.
4. Given selected triangle, generate uniform point in the triangle using [Generate random locations within a triangular domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410054/generate-random-locations-within-a-triangular-domain/47425047#47425047)